# Usecases for this covariant class?

Tags: generics, design-patterns, kotlin, covariance

I've encountered this class

```
sealed class Test<out T> {
}

fun <T, R : T> Test<T>.abc(fn: (Int) -> Test<R>) {
    fn(10)
}
```

In [a reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/8tyqfq/variance_question_in_kotlin_out/) asking why it couldn't be written like this:

```
sealed class Test<out T> {

    fun abc(fn: (Int) -> Test<T>) {
        fn(10)
    }

}
```

I have since wondered where such a sealed class would be useful but couldn't think of anything.

What are example applications of the above `Test` class design?

Comment: It couldn't be useful by itself, it's just a result of simplifying some other code.